# Postfix local delivery causes recipients to not show

Tags: postfix, smtp, my.cnf

I'm quite new to posting, please help me if I'm in the wrong place.
I have a debian email server, which is working for outgoing and incoming with external SMTP service.
postfix, dovecot, mariadb, ispconfig3

The small problem I have, involves local delivery.
When a user sends email, the locally delivered address (same domain) doesn't show up in the recipient list if the recipient isn't on the same server (ie gmail).
This is causing an issue because people do not know who is being cc'd on emails.
ie. me@example.com sends email to you@example.com and johndoe@gmail.com
johndoe@gmail.com will only be able to see himself as the recipients and not you@example.com

I tried disabling local delivery by commenting out virtual_mailbox_domain, but incoming email stopped working.
mydestination has been emptied as well.
I have only one server and I will like it to send email out through the SMTP regardless of domain, and receive incoming email as well.

can someone please kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you share your _main.cf_ file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, but it's not related to postfix.
I was using postmarkapp.com as smtp relay, and their smtp seems to trigger this behavior.
I'm now using amazonses as smtp relay, and the problem disappeared.